# Autodesk Forge ViewingService API: What's going away?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Does anyone (you know who you are) know exactly what is disappearing when Autodesk deprecates the /v1 equivalent of the ModelDerivative API?

I've taken care of everything that was in the blog post here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/autodesk-forge-apis-migrating-from-v1-to-v2.html

But I also have some calls such as:
 /viewingservice/v1/:URN/status

and:
 /viewingservice/v1/items/:dbpath object_ids.json.gz

That were not specifically mentioned. Will these also need to be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These endpoints will no longer be valid. The status of a translation can be obtained by using the [GET :urn/manifest](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) endpoint.

We have [official SDK's](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/quickstarts/v1/overview/) for multiple programming languages that will make it easier to handle the REST calls.

To download the derivatives of a model, the SDK's do not expose direct methods so you actually have to issue the calls "directly". Take a look at the [extract.io](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io) sample that expose the full download workflow, more specifically [there](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/master/server/bubble.js).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer Matt! Btw ... if you can bump up the rep ;)